# Add a Intent in a class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, picasso

I need to start a new activity to show an image in Fullscreen and my Intent is in a class but outside my main class.

```
class PhotoItem(val user: String, val send: String, val timestamp: Long, val country: String): Item<GroupieViewHolder>(){

override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: kotlin.Int) {


    viewHolder.itemView.textView10.text = user
    viewHolder.itemView.textView13.text = timestamp.toString()
    viewHolder.itemView.textView14.text = country
    val uri = send
    val targetImageView = viewHolder.itemView.selectphoto_imageview
    val targetImageViewFullScreen = viewHolder.itemView.fullscreen
    Picasso.get().load(uri).into(targetImageView)
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener{v : View ->

        v.getContext().startActivity(Intent(v.getContext(), FullscreenPhoto::class.java))


    }

}
override fun getLayout(): kotlin.Int {
    return R.layout.photo_from_row


}
}
```

So I found this line : `v.getContext().startActivity(Intent(v.getContext(), FullscreenPhoto::class.java))` because I can't create a basic Intent : `val intent = Intent(this,Home::class.java)startActivity(intent)`

And I need to have the val uri for load the image into my Image view

thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue is that `startActivity` is not available in `PhotoItem`

So change `GroupieViewHolder` class and add activity in constructor like this:

```
class GroupieViewHolder(val activity: Activity, /* other arguments */)
```

Now use that field in `bind` of `PhotoItem` as below:

```
override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: kotlin.Int) {


    // other codes.........

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener{v : View ->

        // using activity field for startActivity
        viewHolder.activity.startActivity(Intent(v.getContext(), FullscreenPhoto::class.java))

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I've not added `val activity : Activity` to `GroupieViewHolder` but to `PhotoItem` and I've added `this@Main` for the activity when I use my class in other fun